# Use stdout/stderr from remote (detached) command execution in screen without file access

Tags: redirect, ssh, stdout, gnu-screen, lxc

I am running isolated bash consoles (in the context of Linux containers/network name spaces) in separate GNU screen sessions on a Linux machine.

I am able to remotely execute commands on these consoles using ssh and screen functionality, as discussed in several other threads, using:

```
ssh <hostname> screen -S <sessionname> -X <cmd>
```

I can also fetch the output from running the above command relying on either the hardcopy-functionality (`screen -S <sessionname> -X hardcopy`) or the logging-functionality (`screen -S <sessionname> -l`), however these all require file access. Similar things happen when the output is redirected to a logfile (using for example "> logfile.txt"), etc.

Is there a way to avoid file access in redirecting the output of the executed command? This would reduce the file access stress on the executing machine. I would like to redirect stdout/stderr data running from within the screen session to the calling environment, such that the output is returned on the screen when executing `ssh <hostname> screen -S <sessionname> ... <magiccommand>`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you want that simply re-attaching to the screen session with `ssh -t <hostname> screen -r <sessionname>` (add `-x` if it's simultaneously attached elsewhere) doesn't do?

Comment: Have you considered using named pipes to shuttle off your output to your remote system via, for example, FTP? A quick search seems to indicate that using the "ftp" command directly is difficult, but I distinctly remember writing a short Perl script using its FTP protocol module which enabled me to do something similar this way. Sorry, it will be a few days before I can check if I still have the script somewhere. Of course, there may be better protocols than FTP for this.

Comment: Named pipes indeed seem to be a solution. I will try this.